# prevent padding and margin from decreasing with css

Tags: html, css

As the screen gets wider the space outside the black portion also stretches. since the `div` with the text have a fixed padding/margin it ends up not remaining constant and the text starts coming on the red portion. How can i tweak the CSS to remedy

[image]

**CSS**

```
    body{
        background-image: url("../desktop_images/contact_bg.jpg");
}

.blackbox{
    width: 37%;
    height:20%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-left:3%;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:35px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display:block;   
    font-size: 18px;
    background-image: url("../desktop_images/contant_diamond.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-color: red;
}


.left{
    color: #008ed2;
    display:block;   
    float:left;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding-left: 55px;

    font-family: futura-pt-bold, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;

}

.right{
    color: #008ed2;
    display:block;    
    float:right;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding-left: 55px;

    font-family: 'futura-pt-bold', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.bottom{
    color: white;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display:block;    
    float:left;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-left: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
}

.bottom2{
    color: white;
    display:block;    
    float:left;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-left: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;/*this is futura demi*/
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
        <div class="blackbox">
            <div class="left">ACTION IS NOT OUR MIDDLE NAME.</div>
            <div class="right">IT'S OUR FIRST</div>
            <div class="bottom">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact us immediately.</div>
            <div class="bottom2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;pasdf@xyz.com<br />xyz@asdf.com</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding is going to give you hard coded results. Use **percentages**, your CSS:

```
.blackbox{
    width: 37%;
    height:20%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-left:3%;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:N%;
    padding-left: 0px;
    display:block;   
    font-size: 18px;
    background-image: url("../desktop_images/contant_diamond.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-color: red;
}


.left{
    color: #008ed2;
    display:block;   
    float:left;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding-left: N%;

    font-family: futura-pt-bold, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;

}

.right{
    color: #008ed2;
    display:block;    
    float:right;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding-left: N%;

    font-family: 'futura-pt-bold', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.bottom{
    color: white;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display:block;    
    float:left;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-left: N%;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
}

.bottom2{
    color: white;
    display:block;    
    float:left;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-left: N%;
    font-weight: 600;/*this is futura demi*/
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
}
```